# Mysql view of multiple entries

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table named POINTS like this one:

```
userid1 | userId2 | points
---------------------------
    1   |    1    |   3
    1   |    1    |   2
    1   |    2    |   5
    2   |    1    |   4
    1   |    3    |   5
```

i am trying to create a view of this table like this one:

```
userId | gained | received | spent | current
--------------------------------------------
   1   |    5   |     4    |  10   |   -1
   2   |    0   |     5    |   4   |    1
   3   |    0   |     5    |   0   |    5
```

where the algorith for the columns would be:

- userId, a unique value of the userIds found in the POINTS table either in userId1 or userId2 column
- gained, the sum of the points where userId1 = userId AND userId2 = userId in the POINTS table
- received, the sum of the points where userId1 != userId AND userId2 = userId in the POINTS table
- spent, the sum of the points where userId1 = userId AND userId2 != userId in the POINTS table
- current, gained + received - spent

i am kinda new to mysql and my problem is that i dont know how to hold sum values for distinctive users if i go into multiple subqueries. any help would be appreciated

update: the numbers in the example are accurate

Comment: Do you have a user table where iduser refer to `userid1` or `userId2` ?

Comment: yes i do have that table

Comment: `spent, the sum of the points where userId1 = userId AND userId2 != userId` This should give `userid : 1 as 10` you have `5` let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: you are right. i rechecked and corrected the numbers

Answer (score 3):

This is a straightforward application of the *structured* part of *structured query language*.

You need two key component subqueries to put this together.  One is the list of points `gained` by each user.  That works like this.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1884/1/0)

```
                      SELECT userid1 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS gained
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 = userid2
                       GROUP BY userid1
```

Similarly, you can generate the spend and received points (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1884/5/0)

```
                      SELECT userid1 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS spent
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 != userid2
                       GROUP BY userid1
```

and (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1884/7/0)

```
                      SELECT userid2 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS received
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 != userid2
                       GROUP BY userid2
```

You also happen to need a subquery that gives you a list of all your distinct users. If you have a separate `user` table you haven't mentioned here, that will work better than this. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1884/9/0)

```
                      SELECT DISTINCT userid1 userid FROM points
                       UNION
                      SELECT DISTINCT userid2 userid FROM points
```

Now, you need to join those four subqueries together, and there's your result. Here's the outline.

```
SELECT a.userid, 
       IFNULL(g.gained,0) gained, 
       IFNULL(s.spent,0) spent,
       IFNULL(r.received,0) received,
       IFNULL(g.gained,0)-IFNULL(s.spent,0)+IFNULL(r.received,0) total
  FROM (   /* all users subquery */
       ) a
  LEFT JOIN (   /* gained subquery */
       ) g ON a.userid = g.userid
  LEFT JOIN (   /* received subquery */
       ) r ON a.userid = r.userid
  LEFT JOIN (   /* spent subquery */
       ) s ON a.userid = s.userid
 ORDER BY a.userid
```

Finally, put it all together like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b1884/13/0)

```
SELECT a.userid, 
       IFNULL(g.gained,0) gained, 
       IFNULL(s.spent,0) spent,
       IFNULL(r.received,0) received,
       IFNULL(g.gained,0)-IFNULL(s.spent,0)+IFNULL(r.received,0) total
  FROM (   /* all users subquery */
                      SELECT DISTINCT userid1 userid FROM points
                       UNION
                      SELECT DISTINCT userid2 userid FROM points
       ) a
  LEFT JOIN (   /* gained subquery */
                      SELECT userid1 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS gained
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 = userid2
                       GROUP BY userid1
       ) g ON a.userid = g.userid
  LEFT JOIN (   /* received subquery */
                      SELECT userid2 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS received
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 != userid2
                       GROUP BY userid2
       ) r ON a.userid = r.userid
  LEFT JOIN (   /* spent subquery */
                      SELECT userid1 AS userid,
                             SUM(points) AS spent
                        FROM points
                       WHERE userid1 != userid2
                       GROUP BY userid1
       ) s ON a.userid = s.userid
 ORDER BY a.userid
```

If you think of it as a four layer club sandwich with the subqueries as slices of cheese and the JOIN clauses as slices of bread, it may be helpful. I admit it's a mouthful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation with case expressions (or ifs) to accomplish what you want.

The base query would look like this:

```
select 
    userid
    , sum(case when u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2 then points else 0 end) gained
    , sum(case when u.userid <> p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2 then points else 0 end) received
    , sum(case when u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid <> p.userId2 then points else 0 end) spent
    , sum(case when u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2 then points else 0 end) 
    + sum(case when u.userid <> p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2 then points else 0 end) 
    - sum(case when u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid <> p.userId2 then points else 0 end) _current
from 
  (select userid1 userid from points union select userid2 from points) u
  , points p
group by u.userid;
```

If you want to create a view based on it the subquery in the from clause needs to be in a view as well. In the fiddle linked below the code has been refactored into several views.

This sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48cb9/1) shows it implemented using views which, given your sample data, outputs:

```
| userid | gained | received | spent | current |
|--------|--------|----------|-------|---------|
|      1 |      5 |        4 |    10 |      -1 |
|      2 |      0 |        5 |     4 |       1 |
|      3 |      0 |        5 |     0 |       5 |
```

Another option, instead of conditional aggregation, would be to use correlated subqueries:

```
select 
    userid
    , (select coalesce(sum(points),0) from points p where u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2) gained
    , (select coalesce(sum(points),0) from points p where u.userid <> p.userid1 and u.userid =  p.userId2) received
    , (select coalesce(sum(points),0) from points p where u.userid =  p.userid1 and u.userid <> p.userId2) spent
from (select userid1 userid from points union select userid2 from points) u;
```

This would produce the same result (but I didn't include the *current* column as it's just a repetition to keep to code short).